# how to use 1D and 2D texture both in a single texture in webgl

Tags: webgl

I was trying to write a fragment shader on webgl which will have 13 uniforms, as i need to do  lots of per pixel calculation , texture atlas mapping , color transformations , etc on a per pixel basis . But all these will change per shape . so when i thought of batching several shapes into one draw call i had to pack all these 13 uniforms per shape into a uniform array . But this uniform array makes my shader execution very slow ( after i cross around 80 - 90 uniforms in a single array ).
Due to this i thought of using 1D texture for all the uniforms , but already i am using a 2D texture atlas in my shader for colors of every pixel . Now how can i use this 1D texture along with the existing 2D . My understanding was we can do only 1 gl.activeTexture() . 
Can any one please help me out . Do i have any other way for packing the uniforms . uniform buffers are not supported with webgl , so had to drop that plan .

Comment: you can use multiple textures. pass 2d texture and additional 1d texture. just alter the `gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE{0|1..30|31})`.

Answer (score 1):

`gl.activeTexture` just sets which *texture unit* you're currently effecting. The texture units are global state. So for example.

```
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE7);  // or gl.TEXTURE0 + 7
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, textureA);
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE9);  // go gl.TEXTURE0 + 9
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, textureB);
```

`textureA` is now bound to texture unit 7 and `textureB` is now bound to texture unit 9.

If you have 2 samplers.

```
uniform sampler2D foo;
uniform sampler2D bar;
```

You can tell each sampler which texture unit to reference like this

```
gl.uniform1i(locationForFoo, 7);  // tell 'foo' to use texture unit 7
gl.uniform1i(locationForBar, 9);  // tell 'bar' to use texture unit 9
```